# How do I access the metadata or the transform information for the output of GDAL function?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gdal, geotiff-tiff, csv

I georeferenced some images using the GDAL module in python and some images using the QGIS function. The output of GDAL was good, but then it did not have any metadata information. For example, if I open a GDAL-georeferenced image in QGIS Georeferencer Module, I do not see any GCP points in QGIS.

[image: GDAL]

But if I open the image that was georeferenced using QGIS in QGIS Georeferencer Module, I can see the GCP points and other transform information.

[image: QGIS]

This becomes a point of concern when I apply the GetGeoTransform() function to the image. For the GDAL-Georeferenced Image, I get the output, "(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)" (which is for sure wrong) and for QGIS georeferenced image, I get the output "(6750659.786576454, 1547.2991105424935, 0.0, 4512931.93309282, 0.0, -1547.2991105424935)", (which is correct). I don't know where I made the mistake in georeferencing. This is a huge problem when I try to convert Pixel Coordinates to Geographical Coordinates.

Here is the code that I used for Georeferencing.

```
 f=pd.read_csv(gcp_points) #for reading the .points from QGIS.
  keep_col = ['mapX','mapY','pixelX', 'pixelY', 'enable', 'dX','dY', 'residual']
  new_f = f[keep_col]
  df = new_f.drop(columns=['enable','dX', 'dY', 'residual'])
  col=['mapX','mapY', 'pixelX','pixelY']
  modified_df = df[col]
  modified_df['pixelY'] = modified_df['pixelY']*(-1)
  gcp_list=[]
# Create a copy of the original file and save it as the output filename:
  out_file= output_raster + 'georeferenced' + os.path.basename(input_raster) 
  src_ds = gdal.Open(input_raster)
  format = "GTiff"
  driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(format)  
  # Open destination dataset
  dst_ds = driver.CreateCopy(out_file, src_ds, 0)
  for index, rows in modified_df.iterrows():
     gcps = gdal.GCP(rows.mapX, rows.mapY, 1, rows.pixelX, rows.pixelY )
     gcp_list.append(gcps)
# Get raster projection
  srs = osr.SpatialReference()
  srs.ImportFromProj4("+proj=aea +lat_1=15 +lat_2=65 +lat_0=30 +lon_0=95 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m no_defs") 
  dest_wkt = srs.ExportToWkt()
# Set projection
  dst_ds.SetProjection(dest_wkt)
  dst_ds.SetGCPs(gcp_list, dest_wkt)
  dst_ds = None
  src_ds = None
```

**Note:** All the Images are georeferenced with the **ESRI:** 102025.